# position the result base on row number in mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this function (refer below)

```
function showMenu(){
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_menu");
$menu = '<nav id="main-menu"><ul class="menuwrapper extend">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $menu .= '<li class="' . $row['status'] . '"><a href="' . $row['url'] . '" class="extend" title="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';
}
$menu .= '</ul></nav>';

return $menu;
}
```

and my database table is structured as follows (refer below)

```
id(BigInt 100, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY)
name(text, utf8_general_ci)
url(varchar 100, utf8_general_ci)
status(text, utf8_general_ci)
key(int 30)
```

The contents of that table are (refer 
below)

```
id = "1", name = "Post", url = "http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/index.php", status="default", key = "0"
id = "2", name = "Pages", url = "http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/pages.php", status="parent", key = "1"
id = "3", name = "Menus", url = "http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/menus.php", status="parent", key = "2"
id = "4", name = "Theme", url = "http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/theme.php", status="parent", key = "3"
```

Now, my question is how could I output the result base on there keys number that each menu has on? my expected output base on what im trying to achieve from the datas above is (refer below)

```
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul class="menuwrapper extend">
        <li class="default">
            <a href="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/index.php" class="extend" title="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/index.php">Post</a>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <a href="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/pages.php" class="extend" title="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/pages.php">Pages</a>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <a href="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/menus.php" class="extend" title="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/menus.php">Menus</a>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <a href="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/theme.php" class="extend" title="http://localhost/gadgetmarket/admin/theme.php">Theme</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see the output was arrange base on keys order. Any recommendations, suggestions and ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, you're not declaring the connection global in your function

```
function showMenu(){
global $con; // SIMPLY ADD THIS LINE
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_menu");
$menu = '<nav id="main-menu"><ul class="menuwrapper extend">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $menu .= '<li class="' . $row['status'] . '"><a href="' . $row['url'] . '"     class="extend" title="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';
}
$menu .= '</ul></nav>';

return $menu;
}
```

and you can use `ORDER BY` to fetch the data the way you want it
`SELECT * FROM user_menu ORDER BY key ASC`